# In Angular, I want to take html of some div but pure html elements not custom elements how to achieve this?

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to get pure html code from particular div in angular I take by document.getEmelmetById But it give me angular type html like custum tags.. I need pure html tags like code... because I want to create pdf so need html tags like understood to browser

Comment: provide a demo use case please. [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `document.getElementById("YourTagID").innerHTML`. Although it will contain your custom tags but they wont cause an issue while generating pdf because when the html parser wont understand these tags and it wont render them. As there is pure html inside these custom tags, the custom tags will get ignored and pdf will be generated fine using the real html tags.